# Is there a way to replace all click events to mouse down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, touch-event

I am creating an interface only for a touch screen and need to be sure that all events are triggered on mousedown since the screen may not register mouseup or click events.  Is there a way to replace all events with mouse down events or some similar plugin that can be sued to ensure proper functionality?

Thanks

Comment: there's "tap" event in jQuery Mobile. http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Comment: You are building that UI with HTML, CSS, …?

Comment: I am building the UI with HMTL & CSS.  I have activated all of the links to work on mouse down but I can not figure how to get the forms to respond on the mouse down event.